# Unity Controller navigating UI

Tags: input, unity, controllers, xbox-controller

I want players to be able to use a controller to navigate our game's menus. We use Unity's new UI, and in the EventSystem have specified a controller axis for our vertical axis. However the selection from the controller is extremely sticky. The joystick must be held down for a second in order for it to move its selected item down.

[image]

I've tried fooling around with the Gravity, Dead and Sensitivty levels but haven't found anything suitable. Could someone recommend some standard settings so the input is not stick7?

I've been using a Xbox controller with a wireless adapter for PC as my controller.

Comment: In the past I've found Unity's default values work pretty well: `Gravity = 0 Dead = 0.19 Sensitivity = 1` - is that not working well for your case?

Comment: I have tried that, but it still feels sticky. I ended up changing the Event System's Input Actions per Second and Repeat Delay values.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the EventSystem's following values:

Input Actions Per Second: 2

Repeat Delay: 0.3

This makes it more responsive, but is not ideal because it involves changing the EventSystem present in every scene. If someone has a better solution, I'd be happy to hear it.